# camel java dsl pass bean method return value to header

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

Java - Apache Camel 2.17 JAVA DSL

My route process the data and return the dates it processed, i want to pass `List<LocalDate>` returned from `myBean.processData` to the log and set in header.

following is my code

```
from("route1")
.bean("myBean","processData")
.log("how do i log the response of processData return")
. setHeader("processDataReturnValue") // how can pass processData return
```

value to header ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is what you are looking for:

```
from("route1")
   .bean("myBean","processData")
   .log("***** processData return value: ${body.toString()} *****")
   .setHeader("myHeader", body());
```

From "Camel in Action" ch. 4. Using beans with Camel:

"At runtime, a Camel exchange is routed, and at a given point in the route, it reaches the BeanProcessor. The BeanProcessor then processes the exchange, performing these general steps:

1. Looks up the bean in the registry
2. Selects the method to invoke on the bean
3. Binds to the parameters of the selected method (for example, using the body of the input message as a parameter; this is covered in detail in section 4.5)
4. Invokes the method
5. Handles any invocation errors that occur (any exceptions thrown from the bean will be set on the Camel exchange for further error handling)
6. **Sets the method’s reply (if there is one) as the body on the output message on the Camel exchange**

I have tested the route using MyBean similar to:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    public List<LocalDate> processData(Exchange exchange) {
        return Lists.newArrayList(LocalDate.now(),
                   LocalDate.now().minusYears(1L));
   }
}
```

P.S. I would consider hiding logging, setting headers and actual bean invocation in a processor.